# I am getting an "error: redefinition of" symbol, even though I have used the same syntax earlier in the file,

Tags: c, function, unit-testing, macros

I am creating a function stub (for a function foo_print_stats()) for a unit test,and have written the following code:

```
static void my_foo_stats(foo_fs_t * const fsys) {
    return;
}
#undef foo_print_stats
#define foo_print_stats my_foo_stats
```

I keep getting the error "redefininiton of my_foo_stats". I have tried changing the name to something else, to no avail. The parameters for my_foo_stats are the exact same as those passed to foo_print_stats. I am confused because I have used the exact same syntax many times int the same file and it has all worked.

Comment: Are you certain your definition of `foo_print_stats` comes before the macro redefinition?  You should look at the preprocessed output, which should instantly show you where the error is.

Comment: first call to this function is before function prototype.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. It might even help you figure out the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the file where the function was initially being defined was getting included below where I was trying to redefine it. thanks to @Tom Karzes for advice